# how to exclude image files within public folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In the `public` folder, I have two folder `hk` and `sg`, they have different image files.
What I want is if I build `hk` package, I only copy images from `hk` folder.
How to exclude the `sg` folder in ember-cli?

Comment: Please add the command you use to build the `hk` package.

Comment: `env country=hk ./node_modules/.bin/ember build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember uses [Broccoli.js](https://broccoli.build/) for it's build pipeline. Broccoli is build around the concept of trees. Please have a look in [it's documentation](https://broccoli.build/about.html) for details.

You could exclude files from the tree using a plugin called [broccoli-funnel](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel). It expects an input node, which could be either a directory name as a string or an existing broccoli tree as a first argument. A configuration object should be provided as a second argument. The files or folders that should be excluded could be specified by `exclude` option on that object.

A broccoli tree is created as part of the build process in `ember-cli-build.js`. The function exported from that file should return a tree. By default it returns the tree created by `app.toTree()` directly. But you could customize that tree using broccoli-funnel before.

This diff shows how default `ember-cli-build.js` as provided by blueprint of Ember CLI 3.16.0 could be customized to exclude a specific file:

```
diff --git a/ember-cli-build.js b/ember-cli-build.js
index d690a25..9d072b4 100644
--- a/ember-cli-build.js
+++ b/ember-cli-build.js
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 'use strict';

 const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
+const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

 module.exports = function(defaults) {
   let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
@@ -20,5 +21,7 @@ module.exports = function(defaults) {
   // please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
   // along with the exports of each module as its value.

-  return app.toTree();
+  return new Funnel(app.toTree(), {
+    exclude: ['file-to-exclude'],
+  });
 };
```

You should explicitly add `broccoli-funnel` to your dependencies even so it's available as a indirect dependency:

```
// if using npm
npm install -D broccoli-funnel

// if using yarn
yarn add -D broccoli-funnel
```

Broccoli-funnel does not only support exact file names but also regular expressions, glob strings or functions to define the files to exclude. Please have a look in [it's documentation](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel#documentation) for details.